# How to show status messages in modal window?

Tags: theming, status-messages

Here, I tried many different ways to show status messages in pop window but was not able to get success in any way. So, basically i want to  show all the status message of site in modal box whether it is configuration message or submit on site of form. Please give suggestion for this if any.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be by installing any from a few modules that do this out of the box

Two of the most used modules are [nicemessages](https://www.drupal.org/project/nicemessages) and [better_messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_messages)